# Matlab ObjectOriented

Tags: matlab, oop

```matlab
> classdef Drone
> properties
> Position
> Target
> Speed
> Bounds % simulation bounds
> end
> 
> 
> methods
> function obj = Drone(bounds,speed)
> obj.Bounds   = bounds;
> obj.Speed    = speed;
> obj.Position = rand(1,2).* bounds;
> obj.Target   = rand(1,2).* bounds;
> end
> 
> function move(obj) % drone goes target
> direction = obj.Target - obj.Position;
> distance  = norm(direction);
> 
> 
> if distance > 0 %drone oves until reach the target
> delta           = (obj.Speed / distance) * direction;
> obj.Position    = obj.Position + delta;
> 
> 
> else
> reached target define new target
> obj.Target = rand(1,2).*obj.Bounds;
> end
> 
> obj.Position = max(0,min(obj.Position, obj.Bounds));
> 
> end
> end
> end
```

main:

```matlab
> bounds = [100,100];
> 
> Drone num
> num_drones = 1;
> 
> Drone objects
> drones = [];
> for i = 1:num_drones
> drone  = Drone(bounds, 5); % speed = 5
> drones = [drones, drone]
> end
> 
> Simulation loop
> num_steps = 100;
> for step = 1:num_steps
> clf; 
> for i = 1:num_drones
> drone = drones(i);
> drone.move();
> plot(drone.Position(1), drone.Position(2), "*");%plot Drones position
> hold on;
> end
> 
> xlim([0, bounds(1)]);
> ylim([0, bounds(2)]); 
> 
> drawnow;
> pause(0.1); % waiting
> end
```

I created a class called `Drone`. In this class, the drone moves from a random place to a random target. I think the class structure is written correctly. However, when plotting in the main part, the drone does not appear to be moving because the new value of `obj.Position` is not taken as a new value by `drone.Position.`.

Comment: You are using a [value class](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html?s_tid=mwa_osa_a) so you need to do `drones = drone.move(); drones(i) = drone;` otherwise the updated class is not being stored in the `drone` variable or the `drones` array. The `move` method should also return `obj`